# String operations with Russian characters in R

Tags: r, string, kaggle

I'm using [Avito's Kaggle Challenge data](https://www.kaggle.com/c/avito-demand-prediction/data) but I'm having trouble with string operations. I'm trying to create a new column with number of uppercase characters. I'm using this code:

```
sum(str_count(description[1], "[А-Я]"))

dput(description[1]) "Кокон для сна малыша,пользовались меньше месяца.цвет серый"
```

but it doesn't work (returns a 0). On the other hand, if I use

```
sum(str_count("Кокон для сна малыша,пользовались меньше месяца.цвет серый", "[А-Я]"))
```

it returns 1, basically telling me that if I get the cell from the data.frame, it won't work, but if I actually write it out, it works. I thought this would be a problem with the class, but they're all chr. What can I do?

Comment: Please copy the result of `dput(description[1])` otherwise we can't help.

Comment: That's right, sorry, I've updated it.